# Error consumiendo WebApi en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Tengo expuesto un WebAPI desarrollado con `C#` pero al consumir la URL `https://myServer.mx/webApiRestSyncService/api/Clients` tengo el error

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que agregar el `Content-Type` que recibe el Api, regularmente es con `JSON` o `XML`

Para `JSON` es `application/json`
Para `XML` es `text/xml`, `application/xml`

**Actualización**

Un cliente que utilizo para probar el consumo de servicios es [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)